# candidate standard functions for 'using'

Tags: c++, generics, idioms

I knew the technique of `using std::swap` to enable via ADL the use of user defined `swap` functions, but I was not aware that this should be applied also to some other functions. For example I was writing abusively `std::abs` in template code wheras I should have used something like:

```
template <class Int> void f(Int i) {
    using std::abs;
    Int j = abs(i);
    // ...
}
```

What standard function can you think of which should be used this way?

On a side note: g++ puts `abs` in the global namespace when including `cstdlib` (in fact `ctsdlib` includes `stdlib.h` (which defines the *function* `abs`) and does a `#undef abs`...), what does the standard says?

Comment: The current standard says that `<cstdlib>` should only provide functions inside the namespace. The new C++11 standard will allow what g++ (and most other compilers) already does.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the standard :

> **3.4.6 Using-directives and namespace aliases**
>   [basic.lookup.udir]
>   When looking up a namespace-name in a using-directive or
>   namespace-alias-definition, only namespace
>   names are considered.

Therefore, you can use the keyword `using` to import variable, types and functions into the current namespace.

---

*EDIT*

You can import anything you like into the current namespace, but you should care for namespace polution, therefore try not to use `using` in headers, but only in the source files.

Ideally, you shouldn't be using this keyword. I use it sometimes when I have deeply nested namespaces.

Comment: this answers what can be imported using 'using', not what should

Comment: @jk Right, because that depends on personal preferences and coding standards. Anyway, I extended my answer

Comment: for the `std::abs` example, it is not that I "like" to import it, but that I _have to_ (unless there exists another solution?) in order for my code to compile with integer-like types, unknown to the std library, but which provide their own version of `abs`.

Comment: @rafak Have to? Can you post an example that fails if you do not import the abs into the current namespace?

Comment: suppose that `abs` is not put in the global namespace: `struct I { I(int i=0) : i(i) {} int i; }; I abs(I i) { return std::abs(i.i); } int main() { I i(-1); i = std::abs(i); /* error! */ using std::abs; i = abs(i); /* OK! */}`. On the other hand, if `I` is `int`, the above will compile only because `std::abs` is brung with using